# Cannot import csv into mysql database using phpmyadmin wizard

Tags: mysql, database, csv, import, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import a csv file into my mysql database using phpmyadmin but keep getting errors.

Here is how the csv looks:

[image]

Then I import like this: 
[image]

And get the error: "Invalid parameter for CSV import: Fields enclosed by". I have tried to put the columns in quotes " or put a semicolon after each column, but keep getting errors.

Comment: I worked through the same issues a few months ago. Ultimately got everything to work...then I found MySQL Workbench - changed my life. Easy, fast, slick and...free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you have an extra field in there. For instance, with your example line of:

```
itemId,date,description,amount
,1,2/13/2013,Fabrics,44
```

the date maps to "description" because of the leading comma, which basically gives an empty (or null, depending on how the import is handled) value to itemId, which doesn't seem to be what you want. Where'd that extra comma come from -- was this an export from some program?

Also, in this case you don't have anything enclosing the fields so you should just be able to leave that value empty, which seems to have worked for you once you got the column count corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the first line of the csv (containing the column names) and that solved the issue. Everything got imported properly.

Note, the date field needed reformatting to match SQL's date format yyyy-mm-dd.